# how to iterate xml nodes with groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to iterate through an xml file with groovy to get some values.
I found many people with the same problem, but the solution they used doesn't work for me, or it's too complicated.
I'm not a groovy dev, so I need a bullet proof solution which I can implement.

Basically I have an xml response file that looks like this:  ( it looks bad but that's what I get)

```
<Body>
 <head>
  <Details>

   <items>
    <item>
     <AttrName>City</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>Rome</AttrValue>
    </item>

    <item>
     <AttrName>Street</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>Via_del_Corso</AttrValue>
    </item>

    <item>
     <AttrName>Number</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>34</AttrValue>
    </item>

   </items>
 
  </Details>
 </head>
</Body>
```

I've already tried this solution I found here on StackOverflow to print the values:

```
def envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText("the xml above")

envelope.Body.head.Details.items.item.each(item -> println( "${tag.name}")  item.children().each {tag -> println( "  ${tag.name()}: ${tag.text()}")} }
```

the best I get is

```
ConsoleScript11$_run_closure1$_closure2@2bfec433
ConsoleScript11$_run_closure1$_closure2@70eb8de3
ConsoleScript11$_run_closure1$_closure2@7c0da10
Result: CityRomeStreetVia_del_CorsoNumber34
```

I can also remove everything after the first println, and anything inside it, the result is the same

My main goal here is not to print the values but to extrapolate those values from the xml and save them as string variables...
I know that using strings is not the best practice but I just need to understand now.

Comment: Those are Node objects. The values are different. The Groovy documentation helped me a lot to understand parsing XML with Groovy. https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as is had 2 flaws:

1. with `envelope.Body` you would NOT find anything
2. if you fix No. 1, you would run into multiple compile errors for `each(item -> println( "${tag.name}")`. Here the `(` is used instead of `{` and you use an undefined `tag` variable here.

The working code would look like:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xmlBody = new XmlSlurper().parseText '''\
<Body>
 <head>
  <Details>

   <items>
    <item>
     <AttrName>City</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>Rome</AttrValue>
    </item>

    <item>
     <AttrName>Street</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>Via_del_Corso</AttrValue>
    </item>

    <item>
     <AttrName>Number</AttrName>
     <AttrValue>34</AttrValue>
    </item>

   </items>
 
  </Details>
 </head>
</Body>'''

xmlBody.head.Details.items.item.children().each {tag ->
  println( "  ${tag.name()}: ${tag.text()}")
}
```

and print:

```
  AttrName: City
  AttrValue: Rome
  AttrName: Street
  AttrValue: Via_del_Corso
  AttrName: Number
  AttrValue: 34
```